# Consume simple WCF service in a client request

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying consume my wcf application with Postman (or simple ajax request), but for some reason, the request always return me:

```
STATUS 400 Bad Request
```

But, from the VS test client, my service works.

**Interface**

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat =  WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle =  WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "general/")]
        MyModel getCourse(int idCourse);
```

**My Class**

```
public MyModel getCourse(int idCourse)
        {
            return null;

        }
```

Some one has an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your code what you tried with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having a similar issue trying to test my WCF service in Postman and I used Chrome's developer tools to figure out the right parameters to pass into the Postman request.

1. Right-click your page in Chrome and select "Inspect Element"
2. Select the "Network" tab and reload a page that executes your WCF request
3. Select the request from the left margin of the "Network" tab, and view the "Request Headers" associated with that request
4. In Postman, add headers that match those that are shown on the "Request Headers" and make sure that the data you pass into the call on Postman matches that of the "Request Payload" listed in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Your VS test client may has an app.config with settings used by runtime to inject into the CLR proxy classes in order to generate a proper SOAP request or Web API request. You may use some Web traffic diagnostic tool like Fiddler to inspect the content of a valid request from your VS client and the bad request from Postman, and compare the difference, and consult what available in VsClient.exe.config, and make appropriate change in Postman.